# RNN model is not learning. The predicted and actual values as attached in the graph is a flat line

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have rescaled, normalized, initialized, dropout the time series forecasting RNN model, yet it is not learning. The predicted and actual values as shown in the graph is flat line at zero.I cannot figure out what the problem is with my model. Your input will be greatly appreicated.Here is the entire code

```
[Predicted and actual value graph[\]\[1\]][1]

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.80)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:]
dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(train)
train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)
test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)  

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):

dataX, dataY = [], []
for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
    a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
    dataX.append(a)
    dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)  

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 40
train_X, train_y = create_dataset(train_scaled, look_back)
test_X, test_y = create_dataset(test_scaled, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
train_X= np.expand_dims(train_X, axis=1)
test_X = np.expand_dims(test_X, axis=1)

print ('Train_X shape', train_X.shape, 'Test_X.shape', test_X.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(64, input_shape=(1,window_size), 
          kernel_initializer = 'random_normal', 
          bias_initializer= 'random_normal'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, kernel_initializer = 'random_normal',
          bias_initializer= 'random_normal'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=0.1)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
#fit network history =model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=2,         

batch_size=32, 
validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=1, shuffle=False)

def predict_and_score(model, X, Y): # Make predictions on the     
original 
    scale of the data. pred =                 
scaler.inverse_transform(model.predict(X))  

    # Prepare Y data to also be on the original scale for   
interpretability. 

    orig_data = scaler.inverse_transform([Y]) # Calculate RMSE. score 
    = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(orig_data[0], pred[:, 0]))  
return(score, pred)
    rmse_train, train_predict = predict_and_score(model, train_X,   
train_y)
    rmse_test, test_predict = predict_and_score(model, test_X, 
test_y)

    print("Training data score: %.2f RMSE" % rmse_train)
    print("Test data score: %.2f RMSE" % rmse_test)


Training data score: 151198.09 RMSE

Test data score: 125302.35 RMSE

[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Your question is too wide for SO and greatly depends on your data and your model. As an advice, you probably want to use LSTM instead of SimpleRNN.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have tried with LSTM in the above code but my model is not learning. Here is the graph. I will appreciate your suggestion to improve the model please.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is with your data: Its range is absolutely ridiculous. While NNs can learn 'anything' in theory, I'd say that it's practically impossible to learn to model output which: (1) is zero most of the time and (2) then ranges up to 1e14.

While the (1) may be intrinsic to your domain, (2) seems unnecessary.

Start by downscaling your data to range [0, 1], that should make it at least possible to learn something.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable comments.Here is the remaining code for further clarification. i have rescaled to (-1,1). There is no improvement with the model.

    # split into train and test sets
    train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.70)
    test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
    train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(train)
    train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)
    test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)
  Test loss:  0.00035600457682967614
  Test accuracy:  0.0

Comment: @Khandu: Please update your question accordingly instead of putting this kind of info in a comment. That way, other people can benefit from it too, thus increasing your chance of actually getting a quality answer.

Comment: Actually i am posting it for the first time in stackflow and not aware of the rules. My comments are being deleted and i am not able to add answers..That is why i posted in the comment..Thank you for the information

Comment: @Khandu No need to apologize, better go and improve your question ;-) There is an "edit" button just bellow the tags. Btw. I only saw your "answer" deleted -- no surprise, it was not an answer to the original question.